# jQuery returning incorrect value of checked radio button when using styled buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, radio-button

I'm using the jQuery plugin [ScrewDefaultButtons](http://screwdefaultbuttons.com/) to style my radio buttons, but it seems it comes with a side effect that it doesn't return the correct value when getting it via jQuery. I am running a function when they are clicked and I am trying to get the value of the radio button the user selected, but it seems to returns the value of the previously selected radio button instead of the one that was just selected.

If I remove the class `pretty_rb`, which disables the styling then it works fine.

I am trying to get the value with:

```
jQuery('input[name=tax_account_type]:checked').val();
```

My HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="tax_account_type" id="individual" class="pretty_rb" value="0" onclick="updateRegForm();" checked required>
<input type="radio" name="tax_account_type" id="business" class="pretty_rb" value="1" onclick="updateRegForm();" required>
```

**Edit:** Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/94UtB/2/

Comment: There must be something else incorrect here, as I am able to get this to work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kellyjandrews/CC2G5/). What is the `updateRegForm()` function doing?

Comment: @KellyJAndrews Sorry, forgot to mention if I disable the styling for the radio buttons then it works fine (as per your example). The `updateRegForm()` is just a simple AJAX function that isn't really relevant to this.

Comment: Got it - can you potentially post the actual interpreted DOM then - basically, is the plugin doing something that is causing trouble?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle that includes the styling?

Comment: Alright, will post a fiddle. Give me a few mins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `ScrewDefaultButtons` wraps the `input` elements in a `div` and then hides the `input` element.
This div has a click event that checks the correct hidden `input` element.
However. Since you have an `onClick` event YOUR event is run before the change.
That is why you get the `old` value.

To solve this add the following code **after** the call to `screwDefaultButtons`:

```
$('.styledRadio').on('click', updateRegForm);
```

or

```
$('.pretty_rb').on('click', updateRegForm);
```

Remember to remove the onlick attribute from the HTML.

Comment: I thought that might be what is happening but I didn't see an event where you could run a function after the `check` event has run so not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for that, but why would I wanna remove the class attribute from the html?

Comment: Sorry... Meant onlick not class.

Comment: Sorry, just about to test it now..... but would you happen to know how to make it apply to just radio buttons inside a certain `ID` as I don't want it to apply to all radio buttons on the page.