# Having trouble with jQuery "on" click

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, jquery-on

I am trying to fire a function from either radio button when they are clicked but it doesn't seem to be working.

My code:

```
$('.radio [name=list_in]').on('click', function() {
    updateListingForm('list_in');
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="fields">
    <div class="radio">
        <div class="pretty_rb styledRadio" style="background-image: url('images/form-radio-icons.png'); width: 19px; height: 20px; cursor: pointer; background-position: 0px -20px;"><input type="radio" checked="" value="auction" class="pretty_rb" id="list_site" name="list_in" style="display: none;"></div><label for="list_site">Site</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <div class="pretty_rb styledRadio" style="background-image: url('images/form-radio-icons.png'); width: 19px; height: 20px; cursor: pointer; background-position: 0px 0px;"><input type="radio" value="store" class="pretty_rb" id="list_store" name="list_in" style="display: none;"></div><label for="list_store">Store</label>
    </div>                    
    <div class="contentClear"></div>
</div>
```

I am using a jQuery plugin to style the radio fields and this is the HTML it outputs, so that is why the normal radio fields are hidden.

I can't use the `onclick` event because of [this reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21019653/jquery-returning-incorrect-value-of-checked-radio-button-when-using-styled-butto); that's why I tried using the `on` here but I can't seem to get it to fire?

What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: Can you assign the click listener to the rendered buttons instead of the ones that are hidden?

Comment: $(document).on('click','.radio [name=list_in]',function(){ updateListingFrom('list_in'); }); 
Try this

Comment: there is something wrong with the way you attach the click event. I think it is not called, I created the this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73mQk/) and it worked. have you wrapped your on click code in a `$(document).ready(function(){/*your code*/})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the listener to the rendered elements instead of the hidden ones:

```
$('.radio .pretty_rb').on('click', function() {
    updateListingForm('list_in');
});
```

Comment: Ahh yeah, how stupid of me, shoulda thought of that haha..... my only problem is I will have to put them inside an ID to avoid it applying to other radio fields on the page, no biggie though.... thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you need a way to differentiate them, but that's the base idea. You're welcome, glad you sorted it out! :) Funny how nobody bothered to read the full question...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('.radio').on('click', function() {
    updateListingForm('list_in');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you miss a $(document).ready(function() {...});

This code works for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.radio [name=list_in]').on('click', function() {
        alert('It works');
    });
});
```

Comment: The on() method seems to only work on viewable elements, you can use a deleagte instead:

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click','.radio [name=list_in]',function(){
      alert("This works");
    });
});